# I'm trying to use multiple filters on my database with laravel

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

I've tried implementing the multiple filters but each time I filter with respect to one it works but when filter with respect to the others the query only takes in one filter.

my Register controller:allCandidates

```js
public function allCandidates(){

        $candidates = new Candidate;

        $queries = [];

        $columns = [
            'field', 'qualification',
        ];

        foreach ($columns as $column) {
            if (request()->has($column)) {
                $candidates = $candidates->where($column, request($column));
                $queries[$column] = request($column);
            }
        }
        if (request()->has('sort')) {
            $candidates =$candidates->orderBy('surname', request('sort'));
            $queries['sort'] = request('sort');
        }
        $candidates =$candidates->paginate(10)->appends($queries);
        return view('contact.candidates', compact('candidates'));
    }
```

Comment: It might be worth having a look at https://github.com/Kyslik/laravel-filterable

Comment: is it always empty result ?

Comment: I can only query with respect to one filter. Once I try to query with respect to another filter, the previously filtered query is gone @MasoudHaghbin

Comment: @RossWilson I'll do so

Comment: You can use 'where' only once, with multiple where's you either use an array as input to the where or you can append with orWhere. https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/queries#where-clauses

Comment: What do you mean by "previously filtered query is gone"?

Comment: The previously Filtered query doesn't append to the New Query in the URL @JonasStaudenmeir

Comment: You want to filter the query by `field` and `qualification`, but it only filters by `qualification`?

Comment: Yes @JonasStaudenmeir

Comment: How do you know that? From the query results? Or did you look at the generated SQL? Did you try LovepreetSingh's answer?

Answer (score 0):

Rewrite code as follows:

```
public function allCandidates(){

        $candidates = new Candidate;

        $columns = [
            'field', 'qualification',
        ];

        foreach ($columns as $column) {
            if (request()->has($column)) {
                $candidates->where($column, request($column));
            }
        }
        if (request()->has('sort')) {
            $candidates->orderBy('surname', request('sort'));
        }
        $candidates->paginate(10);
        return view('contact.candidates', compact('candidates'));
    }
```

Need not to reinitialize **$candidates** variable after once did. Just add filters or call another functions with the object $candidates.